# Less verbose Builder pattern?

Tags: java, builder

When i was reviewing *Builder pattern* in Josh's Bloch book, i came up with simpler implementation, but i'm not sure whether it's proper. 
For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numbers first = new Numbers.Builder().setD(3.14).build();
        System.out.println(first);
        Numbers second = new Numbers.Builder().setI(17).setF(1.24F).build();
        System.out.println(second);
        System.out.println(first);
    }
}

final class Numbers {
    private int i;
    private long l;
    private float f;
    private double d;

    private Numbers() {}


    public static class Builder {
        private final Numbers instance = new Numbers();

        public Builder setI(int i) {
            instance.i = i;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setL(long l) {
            instance.l = l;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setF(float f) {
            instance.f = f;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setD(double d) {
            instance.d = d;
            return this;
        }

        public Numbers build() {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%4d %4d %7.3f %7.3f", i, l, f, d);
    }
}
```

Is it can still be considered as a *Builder pattern* or i missed something?

**EDIT**

What about this?

```
//...

private Numbers() {}


private Numbers(Numbers o) {
        i = o.i;
        l = o.l;
        f = o.f;
        d = o.d;
    }

public static class Builder {
        private final Numbers instance = new Numbers();

          //...

        public Numbers build() {
            return new Numbers(instance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One big problem with this approach is that if you call build() several times on the same builder, you end up with the same instance every time.

Comment: @JB Nizet oh, right, Builder is public -_- ty

Comment: Create the Builder instance inside the build() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that if you call `build` twice for the same `Builder` instance, you'll get the same `Numbers` instance. And if you call methods of the `Builder` after you called `build` and got the `Numbers` instance, you will change that instance. The instance created by the builder should be independent of the Builder once it's built.

Comment: The other problems with this are that it means none of your fields can be `final`, and your constructor can't perform any validation on the fields (maybe you want some logic that depends on multiple fields, like "if i == 3 then f can't be negative").

Comment: @yshavit so now(after edit) the disadvantage of this approach is that i cannot check invariants?

Comment: @DmytroD there is another problem: many times, the immutable object constructed by the builder doesn't have one field for every mutator of the builder. Imagine for example that a Numbers instance is made of two PairOfNumbers immutable instances. You generally want to have a distinction between the way the immutable instance stores its permanent state and the way the mutable builder stores its mutable state.

Comment: @JB Nizet as i understand you, then — I can make defensive copy in constructor  `Numbers(Numbers o)`

Comment: @DmytroD if there is no `i` field in Numbers, where will you store `i` when `setI()` is called?

Comment: @JB Nizet oh, i see, you mean it can turn out in misbehaviour when i'll change my `Numbers`?

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that if your Number class has two fields `PairOfNumbers iAndL` and `PairOfNumbers fAndD` you won't be able to store `i` in the Numbers instance when setI() is called, since Numbers doesn't have any field where `i` can be stored.

Comment: Also three fact that your fields aren't final, which could have maintainability and multi-threading implications.